# Can Apache clean cookies from a request to specific URLs?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, cookies, http-cookie

We have the following configuration:

```
<Directory /docs>
    AuthFormAuthoritative Off
    AuthType None
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Problem: I do not want any cookie will be send to the Apache directory with documents (URLs started with `/docs`) even a user visit first a main site that requires the authentication.

Is it possible to do with Apache?
What configuration should I add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try to use `mod_headers` and:

```
RequestHeader unset Cookie
```

All credits goes to stackoverflow dudes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798431/how-to-remove-a-cookie-in-apache